# How to read the map key and value from the .csv file in c++?

Tags: c++, json, csv

Below is the data stored in the .csv file

```
TestCaseName:MapUInt64String16VectFloat64ReqProvOp,key:CTMapUInt64String16Ve
ctorFloat64Op,value:{123:u"98"};
```

Under the above value mentioned is the `map<uint64_t, std::16string>`
so here key return type is `uint64_t` and its data is `123` and the value return type is `std::u16string` its value is `u"98"`.

I need to read those csv file and whole content have to be printed on the terminal as the output. while I am reading the map value i have mentioned  like this

```
//empty map
std::map<uint64_t, std::u16string> myMap;
  
//string16 to string conversion
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> actual;
std::string val = actual.to_bytes(myMap.begin()->second);

file.ReadFile("CTString16Int32Op", val);
```

I was tried to  run this, but I am getting runtime error as mentioned below:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I thought that, while reading the map value is the issue. So please try to give me the best solution for how to read the map value data from the .csv file in c++.

Comment: If you have an empty map what do you suppose `myMap.begin()->second` does?

Comment: Actually, This code is useful for the request and response. and I need to sync to the request so i am passing that empty map and object of that response type

Comment: You might consider putting together a [mcve]. I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but if the map is empty then using `myMap.begin()->second` is undefined behavior.